# Let $A,B\subseteq \Bbb R $such that A and B are bounded, show that AB is bounded

Tags: real-analysis

$AB=\lbrace ab \mid a\in A , b\in B \rbrace$.

Let $M$ is an upper bound of $A$ and $N$ is an upper bound of $B$.
Then can we say that $MN$ is upper bound of $AB$?
So how can we prove that $AB$ is bounded?

Answer (score 1):

No $MN$ won’t be the upper bound of $AB$. Take the example of $A=[-1,0]$ and $B=\{1\}$.

However if $m$ is such that $\vert a \vert \le m$ for all $a \in A$ and $n$ is such that $\vert b \vert \le n$ for all $b \in B$, $mn$ is such that $\vert x \vert\le mn$ for all $x \in AB$. That proves that $AB$ is indeed bounded.

Comment: So how can we prove it

Answer (score 0):

$A, B$ are bounded, let $S,T$ be the bounds for $A,B$ resp., i.e.

$|a|\lt S$,  $a \in A$, $|b| \lt T$, $b \in B$.

$AB:=${$ab| a \in A, b \in B$}

For $ab \in AB$:

$|ab|=|a||b| \lt ST$, i .e. $AB$  is bounded.